# SourceTree Terminal prompting for password but repo authentication is done via SSH

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm running into an issue where whenver I try to open the terminal for a repository in Sourcetree and I perform a command e.g. `git push`, I am prompted for a password. The weird thing is that the repository authentication is done via ssh. The normal controls in the GUI work fine for pulling/pushing and doesn't prompt me for a password.

[image: Terminal prompting for password]

I have set up SSH configuration like so (which works fine for the regular Sourcetree GUI):

[image: SSH config]

As per this thread with a similar issue: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/ssh-key-in-sourcetree-terminal/qaq-p/137178 I have copied the privkey.ppk to `C:\Users\Niels\.ssh\`.

Pageant shows the private key as being added too:
[image: Pageant]

Why can I not perform Git operations on my repository from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Git uses different format for keys than `pagent` and `pagent` is only usable for SourceTree not for Git system. You have to generate a new ssh key with `ssh-keygen` and you have to add that key to git server you want to use. Open a terminal **(GitBash)** and apply the following steps:

1. `cd ~/.ssh`
2. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096`
3. `cat id_rsa.pub | clip`

Last command would copy the new public key to the clipboard. You can add it to Git server just bye pasting in the mentioned text box.